# Turning off management of content types

Tags: list, content-type

I have a list with aproximately 100 records. It has management of content types turned on. There is one content type and all the records are that content type. If I turn off management of content types will I lose any of my data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning off Management of content type will not have any impact on your existing data,  it will just stop displaying options to manage your content type.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to turn management of content types off?

You can leave it on, and remove all other content types from the available options in the settings of the list – this basically effects the list in that way that there is only your content type as possible content type.

No data lost, and you could still add additional content types later, if ever needed.